# Monoid instance for ParMap?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, monoids

Is there an existing `Monoid` instance for `scala.collection.parallel.ParMap` in Cats?  I don't think so, but I am not certain.

If not, then how would I go about creating such an instance?  Here is what I have so far...

```
import cats._
import implicits._

def parMapMonoid[K, V]: Monoid[ParMap[K, V]] = {
  new Monoid[ParMap[K, V]] {
    def combine(v1: ParMap[K, V], v2: ParMap[K, V]): ParMap[K, V] = {
      ???
    }
    def empty: ParMap[K, V] = {
      ParMap.empty[K, V]
    }
  }
}
```

...you can assume that there is an appropriate `Monoid` instance defined for the type `V`.  For the specific use case I have in mine `type V=Int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This combines the values pointwise, missing values for a key `k` are replaced by the identity element of the `V`-monoid:

```
def parMapMonoid[K, V](implicit vMon: Monoid[V]): Monoid[ParMap[K, V]] = {
  new Monoid[ParMap[K, V]] {
    def combine(v1: ParMap[K, V], v2: ParMap[K, V]): ParMap[K, V] = {
      val allKeys = v1.keys ++ v2.keys
      (for (k <- allKeys) yield {
        (k, vMon.combine(
          v1.getOrElse(k, vMon.empty),
          v2.getOrElse(k, vMon.empty)
        ))
      })(collection.breakOut)
    }
    def empty: ParMap[K, V] = {
      ParMap.empty[K, V]
    }
  }
}
```

Since the `allKeys` is also a parallel collection, the whole construction should still be "reasonably parallelized".

Answer (score -1):

If you need to just somehow combine `ParMap`s then you <s>can just use regular `Monoid[Map[_, _]]`</s> . No, unfortunately, you can't since `ParMap` is not a subtype of `Map`.
But if you want to leverage ideomatic FP you should avoid structures like `ParMap` since they mix description of data and execution model.

Comment: I don't understand how one "can just use regular `Monoid[Map[_,_]]`". Can you please elaborate? Good point about need to avoid structures like ParMap when writing idiomatic FP.